# The parameters 'showinfo' and 'rel' doesnt work with the new player version

Tags: iframe, youtube-iframe-api

When I set the config to the iframe with the new player version, it doesn't work.

**I'm setting the config on this way on the iframe URL:**

```
<iframe src="{{url}}?controls=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&modestbranding=0&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=1" ... />
```

This is the [gist of the `debug info`](https://gist.github.com/lquintana/51c5d764d8a2653ed341b2b0f61b0b56) of the player

Anyone have a clue about this? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed. After clearing the browser data both the player on my site and the [Youtube Player Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) are working as expected. When setting `rel=0` and `showinfo=0` for the url in the iframe, the title and the related videos disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update in case you experience any new behaviour with the mentioned parameters.

According to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

`showInfo` is now deprecated & the default behaviour of `rel` has changed so `0` no longer disables videos instead it shows additional videos from the same channel.